Question about Path Integrals and Exchange Statistics in Steve Simon's "Topological Quantum"
In the introduction to the path integral approach leading to exchange statistics for many particles, Steve Simon breaks up the sum of paths into two types: paths where particles do not exchange (type 1) and paths where particles do exchange (type -1). He asserts that it is completely valid to have (sum type 1−sum type -1) instead of ( sum type 1 + sum type -1)
I am struggling to understand why this is the case. Since this is a probability amplitude, taking the magnitude squared seems like the minus sign would change the outcome. However, Simon asserts that this is fine as long as the phases obey composition rules. Could someone explain why the subtraction approach is valid and how the relative phase does not alter the probability amplitude?  I understand that for fermions this turns out to be correct since we do accumulate a phase of -1 under exchange, I'm just a bit confused at his presentation since he seems to disregard that the amplitude may change and only addresses whether there is consistency under composition. Are there more fundamental principles at work here?

I don't see a problem with the minus sign changing the probabilities. Fermions are different from bosons.

I'll repeat what mike stone has said, just using a few more words -- as you say, there are two possibilities for representations of $S_{n}$ on $U(1)$: the trivial representation and the sign representation. Hence, in principle there are two distinct families of identical particles in three or more spatial dimensions: those with bosonic exchange phases, and those with fermionic exchange phases. Since these two systems of identical particles are distinct possibilities, why should we expect the propagator to be the same for both of them?

Thank you both.  It seems like the starting point is assuming that there may be some physically observable difference between particles corresponding to different representations of the group of paths through some space since the path integral only cares about consistency under composition and unitarity wrt phases (please correct me if I'm wrong here).  We do observe fermions, bosons, etc which confirms this approach.  A follow-up question is:  do we also see different kinds of phases for different kinds closed trajectories for just one particle (closed loops, a line going in and out etc)?

@SAlvi All trajectories for one point-particle are topologically equivalent to 'doing nothing', so there aren't any distinct trajectories to distinguish between. But if you account for $2\pi$ rotations, then your group of 1-particle trajectories is given by $\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e. the number of clockwise rotations of the particle). E.g. For fermions, you get a $+1$ or $-1$ phase depending on the parity of the rotations in the 1-particle trajectory. The spin-statistics theorem links the behaviour of many identical particles (exchange statistics) with that of a single constituent particle (spin).
